# Visiting the US after overstay as a minor

Tags: usa, esta, overstaying, minors, us-visa-waiver-program

I found stories related to mine but none answered how I should fill out the Visa Waiver Program ESTA form. I moved to the US with my mother when I was 9 years old and left when I was 12 (with a Brazilian passport). We became illegal on the last month we were there.

Now, 11 years later, I wish to go back to the US for a visit. I recently got my Italian citizenship and passport, so I would go under the Visa Waiver Program.
I’ve seen answers here in which most people could go back through the VWP.

Should I answer “yes” or “no” on the ESTA form to the question that asks if I ever overstayed in the US?

Although illegal, I was a minor the whole time I was there.

Could anyone who’s been/has a kid who’s been through a similar situation help me, please?

Comment: I saw that other question but there were no answers related to filling out the form. What i need to know is if i should put a "yes" or a "no" in the form.

Comment: @MarinaG93 I'm afraid site policy still is to close as a duplicate and draw attention to the older question. However you as a new user do not have the rep to do so, which is unfortunate. In this case I am also interested in the answer and will place a bounty there.

Comment: You should answer Yes.

Comment: @user102008, has this ever happened to you? If i answer "yes", will there be a background check as to when i was illegal so they'll know it happened when i was a minor?

Comment: If you answer "no", they'll eventually find out that you overstayed as a minor and then *something* bad because you lied on your application. (I don't know what will happen exactly)